# How to set what application to open a file based on file extension on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, file-association

In my Mac OS X 10.5, it has set all my *.patch files to open with 'Notepad in Windows via Parallel'.

I have tried to change it by

1. click 'Open With..'
2. select 'TextEdit'
3. check the 'Always Open With' box

But still when I get new *.patch file, it will set to open 'Nodepad in Windows' by default.

Can you please tell me how can I change that for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply select a file of the specified type, then choose **Get info** from the File menu. In the **Open with** section, choose your desired program from the menu and click the **Change All** button.

[**RCDefaultApp.prefPane**](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/22977) is a nice frontend which makes this easier.

Comment: Thanks. That saves me a lot of time. I often click it by mistake and it goes and launch Parallel... and then NotePad...